# 2010 SharePoint Designer Workflow Task Process

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, tasks

I re-built a 2013 WF on 2010 platform so I can have WF#1 trigger this (now 2010) WF#2. The WF runs, but the task doesn't send. If I change the task to an email it works fine. Is there some setting or something about 2010 Tasks I'm not seeing that must be enabled in order for them to send? This is what the step looks like. Again if that is "email mark" it works fine, but send a task doesn't seem to trigger somewhere:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer at least for me this works. I had to right-click the Task in my workflow and go to Properties. Scroll down to SendDefaultTaskNotification -- which is set to NO by default-- and change to Yes.

[image]